# How to implement Google Sign-In in Android with Compose using a backend server?

Tags: android, google-oauth, android-jetpack-compose

I have created two apps on Google API Console, one for the client and one for the server. I have correctly added the `SHA-1` to the client and both apps are using the correct client id's and respective secrets.

In the MainActivity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var signInLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>
    private val authViewModel: AuthViewModel by viewModels()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(BuildConfig.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

        val mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

        val signInLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.data)
            handleSignInResult(task)
        }

        setContent {
            AuthServiceTheme {
                Surface {
                    NavGraph(mGoogleSignInClient, signInLauncher)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
        try {
            val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            val idToken = account?.idToken

            // Send ID token to backend server
            if (idToken != null) {
                authViewModel.onAuthEvent(AuthEvent.Submit(AuthOperation.GOOGLE_OAUTH, token = idToken))
            }
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            // Sign in failed
            e.message?.let { Log.d("FAILED", it) }
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation for google sign:

```
override suspend fun googleSignIn(idToken: String): AuthResult<Unit> {
   return try {
        val request = GoogleSignInRequest(idToken)
        val response = authApi.googleSignIn(request)


        val response = authApi.googleSignIn(GoogleSignInRequest(idToken))
        preferencesManager.saveAuthToken(response.token)

        AuthResult.Authorized()
    } catch (e: HttpException) {
        val errorMessage = e.response()?.errorBody()?.string() ?: "Unknown error"
        // Error handling
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        AuthResult.UnknownError(e.message ?: "Unknown error")
    }
}
```

then the NavGraph is passing the `googleSignInClient` and `signInLauncher` to the Signup screen and in the signup screen :

```
@Composable
fun SignupScreen(
    signInLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>,
    googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient,
) {
    OAuthClientButton(
       "Continue with Google",
        R.drawable.ic_launcher_google,
    ) {
       val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
       signInLauncher.launch(signInIntent)
    }
}
```

The backend api is working at "http://localhost:8080/login/google" and is working fine when I run that url in the browser, as in, the user is saved to the db. But when I run it from the Android Studio AVD, takes me to the google account selection popup and after selecting the account I want to login with the popup just closes and then nothing else happens. Looking at the backend server logs I can see that the respective route, "/login/google" is never reached.

How can I update this code to actually have the client make the request to the backend server and save the user to db?

Comment: is your `handleSignInResult` getting called? does it have a token?